# Python: how can I Insert mp3 to one Mp4 Video at specific time

Tags: python, video, mp3, mp4

I am new to Python. Now I have 1.mp3 file and 1.mp4 file.

The mp3 file is short and lasts 1s. The path of mp3 is C:/1.mp3
The mp4 file is longer and lasts 20s. The path of mp4 is C:/1.mp4

I want to insert the 1.mp3 to the 1.mp4 at 5s and 10s

How can I do it? Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
from moviepy.editor import *

clip = VideoFileClip("1.mp4")
audio = AudioFileClip("1.mp3")
clip.audio = CompositeAudioClip([audio, clip.subclip(1, 5).audio.set_start(1), audio.set_start(5), clip.subclip(6, clip.duration).audio.set_start(6)])
clip.write_videofile('final_video.mp4', codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it is a little different. I want to insert the 1s long audio to the mp4 at 5s (the 5s point in the mp4)

Comment: @todaytoplist Please see the edited solutuion.